# SMS not sending even if the phone number is verified - 400 Error Code

Tags: python, twilio, http-status-code-400

I signed up with Twilio Yesterday for educational purposes and just trying to send myself a SMS. But it keep giving me 400 - Bad Request Error.

I am from a high-risk country but Twilio has automatically updated my Geo Permissions. I am using Python and there is no errors in my code.

Python Error:

> twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: The number +947XXXXXXXX is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send messages to unverified numbers;

This error occurs when i try to send the SMS from python application as well as Twilio Console as a testing message. I do not want to spend on buying a pro account just yet. I tried to add a new Caller ID in Verified Caller IDs, but now it's not sending the OTP as well, for which i tried with all possible ways. Is the 'Extension' the country code? Please provide a solution. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I understand your confusion; let me try to explain it. To combat spam and phishing on Twilio's platform, trial users can only access a certain subset of services and their features. One restriction is that you can only communicate with your own phone numbers. These numbers are referred to as [Verified Caller IDs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-How-to-Add-and-Remove-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio).

Comment: Well, it is my own number that I am trying to send the sms.

Comment: Then you should be able to register this number as a verified caller id as explained in the link above

Comment: Does not sent the verification code.

Comment: I'm sorry. This seems like a case for support than as it's not a issue with the code or the SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I was able to manually add my number to the verified list with the help of Twilio's support. This must be a bug.